# JavaFX ListView

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `ListView<String> list`. I can easily get the next item in the ListView with a button using this code:

```
 public void toNext(){
    list.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
 }
```

But if I want to go through the ListView automatically with a button, it won't work. I tried the following code:

```
 public void play(){
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getItems().size() ; i++) {
            list.getSelectionModel().select(i);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

This code doesn't select the different strings in the list but just skips to the last string after the given waittime. How can I get it to select each string in the list with a delay of 500 ms?

Comment: This is probably because you do not call `lijst.getSelectionModel().select(i);` in the UI thread, meaning play is not called on the UI thread, as it should not be.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo but that's not the problem ;) @hotzst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an animation:

```
Timeline animation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> list.getSelectionModel().selectNext()));
list.getSelectionModel().select(0);
animation.setCycleCount(list.getItems().size()-1);
animation.play();
```

Advantages to this approach include

1. It is lightweight, and doesn't involve creating a new thread of execution. It simply hooks into the existing FX Application Thread and pulse mechanism.
2. The code is cleaner.
3. It has additional built-in API, so it is much easier to stop or pause the animation than it would be if you created a new thread to manage this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, your loop completely runs in FxApplicationThread.
So, the UI won't update during the loop.

Better would be something like:

```
public void play(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < lijst.getItems().size(); i++) {
                final int idx = i;
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lijst.getSelectionModel().select(idx);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the call that makes the UI update in the UI thread otherwise all the updates are done in one bunch at the end, hence it jumps to the end of the list.

```
 public void play(){
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getItems().size() ; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                list.getSelectionModel().select(index)
            });
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: It will wait 500ms and then select the first one and the last one, but the ones in between won't get selected...